# Can i use ado.net with signalR

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, signalr, offline

I am currently working with signalR and its purely new to me.and i have to bulid a application, in that i want to display signalR interaction with database and wants to display a gridview/html table an wants to perform crud operations. and that chages must reflect instantly on other browsers. i have done lots of google but i am not getting any example that help me.So please if any one has any demo application that interact with db using ado.net please help me out i am very thank ful to you

Comment: Searching for tools/tutorial is off-topic on SO. There are plenty of example of working with DB in C#. If you have specific code that you can't make working with SignalR - it will likely be ok question...

Comment: You can use use AJAX with jQuery for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use Ado.net with signalr follow this link given below for the demo application

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/broadcast-sql-data-using-signalr-in-Asp-Net/